# Replace Backslash with Forwardslash in Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am writing a simple batch script to get the filenames in a folder and write the output to a file. At the same time, I am appending a string to the file.

```
  @echo off
  set $string=!source ./
  set "loc=C:\path\to\dir\files\scripts\"

  pushd %loc%
  (for %%a in (*) do (
  echo %$string%%%~dpnxa))>output.txt
  popd
```

**output.txt:**

```
  !source ./C:\path\to\dir\files\scripts\abc.txt
  !source ./C:\path\to\dir\files\scripts\xyz.txt
```

I am having a hard time replacing backslash `\` with forward-slash `/` in the output and also removing this part `C:\path\to\dir\files\` from the path.

In the end, I am trying to achieve something like this written to a file:

**final_output.txt:**

```
  !source ./scripts/abc.txt
  !source ./scripts/xyz.txt
```

Any help will be great.

Comment: `%%~dpnxa` (which is equivalent to `%%~fa`) returns full paths, but I think you want `%%~nxa` to return pure file names. To get the parent name `scripts` you could do this: `for %%a in (*) do for %%b in ("%%~dpa.") do echo(%$string%%%~nxb/%%~nxa`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
set "$string=!source ./"
set "loc=U:\path\to\dir\files\scripts\"

pushd %loc%
FOR %%a IN ("%loc%.") DO SET "locparent=%%~dpa"
(for %%a in (*) do (
 SET "line=%%~dpnxa"
 CALL SET "line=%$string%%%line:%locparent%=%%"
 CALL ECHO %%line:\=/%%))>output.txt

popd
GOTO :EOF
```

[I used drive u: for testing]

Yo can't substring a metavariable (`%%a` in this case) - you need to transfer to a uservariable.

Having established `line`, use `call set` to execute the command `SET "line=valueof$string%line:valueofloc=%"`, which replaces the unrequired string already in `line` by *nothing*.

Then use `call echo` to execute `ECHO %line:\=/%`, replacing any remaining `\` with `/`.

Your narrative states you wish to remove `C:\path\to\dir\files\scripts` from the output, but your example output includes `scripts`.

[adjusted include the leafname]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I am trying to achieve. Regards to my narrative with the path, I missed making changes to the path. The output I needed remains the same. Appreciate the help